# Error ORA-06530 from function that returns an object type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following function `GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD` which returns the type `ld_data_type`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ld_data_type AS OBJECT(collected NUMBER, uncollected NUMBER);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD (VAPPOINTOFCAID    NUMBER,
                                                 VPREVLIQUIDATE    NUMBER,
                                                 VCURRLIQUIDATE    NUMBER,
                                                 VNEXTLIQUIDATE    NUMBER,
                                                 YEPT              NUMBER)
   RETURN LD_DATA_TYPE
AS
   OUT_VAR        LD_DATA_TYPE;
   VNETV23        NUMBER;
   VNETV24        NUMBER;
   VCURR23        NUMBER;
   VCURR24        NUMBER;
   VCOLLECTED     NUMBER;
   VUNCOLLECTED   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM (NETX) - SUM (NETP)
     INTO VNETV23
     FROM VIEW_CUSTOMER_TRN4INVS4LD
    WHERE APPOINTOFCAID = VAPPOINTOFCAID AND VAT = ABS (1.23);

   SELECT SUM (NETX) - SUM (NETP)
     INTO VNETV24
     FROM VIEW_CUSTOMER_TRN4INVS4LD
    WHERE APPOINTOFCAID = VAPPOINTOFCAID AND VAT = ABS (1.24);

   VCOLLECTED := 0;
   VUNCOLLECTED := 0;

   CASE
      WHEN YEPT = 0
      THEN
         VCURR24 := VCURRLIQUIDATE - VNETV24;

         CASE
            WHEN VCURR24 > 0
            THEN
               VCOLLECTED := VNETV24 * 1.24;
               VCURR23 := VCURRLIQUIDATE - VNETV23;

               CASE
                  WHEN VCURR23 > 0
                  THEN
                     VCOLLECTED := -999;
                  ELSE
                     VCOLLECTED :=
                        VCOLLECTED + ( (VCURRLIQUIDATE - VCURR24) * 1.23);
               END CASE;
            ELSE
               VCOLLECTED := -1999;
         END CASE;
      ELSE
         OUT_VAR.COLLECTED := -888;
         OUT_VAR.UNCOLLECTED := -889;
   END CASE;

   SELECT VCOLLECTED, VUNCOLLECTED
     INTO OUT_VAR.COLLECTED, OUT_VAR.UNCOLLECTED
     FROM DUAL;

       /*
OPEN buffer_cur;
FETCH buffer_cur INTO out_var.val1, out_var.val2;

CLOSE buffer_cur; */


   RETURN OUT_VAR;
END GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD;
```

When I call the function like

```
select GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD(171231, 42240, 31680, 0, 0) from dual;`
```

I get an error:

```
Execution (50: 8): ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
ORA-06512: at "C##SOLSA.GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD", line 56
```

I'm use Oracle 12c Standard edition.

How should I be calling the function `GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD` and Where is the problem that causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize your object type `OUT_VAR` before you can set its properties like this:

```
OUT_VAR:= LD_DATA_TYPE(0,0);
```

See the details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i7530).

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you haven't initialised your object variable:

```
...
   RETURN LD_DATA_TYPE
AS
   OUT_VAR        LD_DATA_TYPE := new LD_DATA_TYPE(null, null);
...
```

Your logic is slightly confused though; at the end of your case you do:

```
  ELSE
     OUT_VAR.COLLECTED := -888;
     OUT_VAR.UNCOLLECTED := -889;
```

but then overwrite the value immediately afterwards with:

```
   SELECT VCOLLECTED, VUNCOLLECTED
     INTO OUT_VAR.COLLECTED, OUT_VAR.UNCOLLECTED
     FROM DUAL;
```

Possibly you meant to set `VCOLLECTED` and `VUNCOLLECTED` in that `ELSE`. If you did that then you wouldn't need to initialise `OUT_VAR`, as the first remaining reference would create it; which you could do as:

```
  OUT_VAR := LD_DATA_TYPE (VCOLLECTED, VUNCOLLECTED);
```

instead of selecting from dual; or you could not have the local variable at all and just do:

```
...
  ELSE
    VCOLLECTED := -888;
    VUNCOLLECTED := -889;
  END CASE;

  RETURN LD_DATA_TYPE (VCOLLECTED, VUNCOLLECTED);
END GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD;
```

Comment: call of function is `select
    iv.ld_data_type.collected,
    iv.ld_data_type.uncollected
from
    (select
        GET_UN_COLLECTED_4LD(171231, 42240, 31680, 0, 0) as ld_data_type from dual) iv;`

Comment: @Giorgos - the call is OK. With the changes I made, and no real data, I get -1999 and 0. You could probably do this without any PL/SQL, or certainly with simpler logic.

Comment: You have right the -1999 is problem and I am try to find why.

Comment: Well that's a different question, and you'd need to provide the table data for us to be able to see why VNETV24 ends up <= 31680, which seems to be how you'd end up there.